# iterate over map json in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm having some problems trying to use the data from this type of json

```json
{
    "content_module": {
        "authz.provider_3": [
            "User 10",
            "User 11",
            "User 18",
            "User 2",
            "User 3",
            "User 5"
        ],
        "authz.provider_2": [
            "User 13",
            "User 15",
            "User 16",
            "User 17",
            "User 8",
            "User 9"
        ],
        "authz.provider_4": [
            "User 0",
            "User 1",
            "User 12",
            "User 19",
            "User 6",
            "User 7"
        ],
        "authz.provider_1": [
            "User 14",
            "User 4"
        ]
    },
    "auth_module": {
        "authn.provider_4": [
            "User 2",
            "User 5",
            "User 9"
        ],
        "authn.provider_2": [
            "User 1",
            "User 10",
            "User 13",
            "User 14",
            "User 16",
            "User 18",
            "User 6",
            "User 8"
        ],
        "authn.provider_3": [
            "User 0",
            "User 11",
            "User 12",
            "User 15",
            "User 7"
        ],
        "authn.provider_1": [
            "User 17",
            "User 19",
            "User 3",
            "User 4"
        ]
    }
}
```

I`m using axios within react, but when i perform a get method and store the data in a state, then when i try to use a forEach method, i recive this type of error.

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {authz.provider_3, authz.provider_2, authz.provider_4, authz.provider_1}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

This is the get method:

```
const [contentModules, setContentModules] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/usuarios/filtrados')
      .then(res => {
        setContentModules(res.data.content_module);
        setAuthModules(res.data.auth_module);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
  }, [])
```

Comment: the error message makes it clear the problem isn't with this code, it's with something you're rendering in this component. Presumably you have `{content_modules}` somewhere - but you can't just do that, you presumably want to use these values to determine what exactly gets rendered, but exactly what you want to render depends entirely on what application you're building.

Comment: Yep, 100% what @RobinZigmond said. Can you show the relevant rendering code as well?

Answer (score 0):

Error is clear you can't use forEach to loop on object
if you want to loop the whole module you can use `Object.values(res.data.content_module)` that will return array of arrays like that `[[],[],[]]`
or if you want to loop keys use `Object.keys(res.data.content_module)` will return array of keys [ "authz.provider_1", "authz.provider_2"]